# Magento Module System

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, module

When we disable module from System > Configuration > Advanced Which type of file still we can access And which type of File cannot access?

Comment: is my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your module uses, let’s say some Observer functionality to hook into some part of the system and does some overriding then those actions won’t be disabled.

For Further Information goto this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-fully-disable-turn-off-magento-module/)

Comment: Whats about block and model files?

Comment: it depends what you write in block and model files. but I can say that it should be affected.